# JQuery Find #ID, RemoveClass and AddClass

Tags: jquery, find, addclass, removeclass

I have the following HTML

```
<div id="testID" class="test1">
        <img id="testID2" class="test2" alt="" src="some-image.gif" />
    </div>
```

I basically want to get to #testID2 and replace .test2 class with .test3 class ?

I tried

```
jQuery('#testID2').find('.test2').replaceWith('.test3');
```

But this doesn't appear to work ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
jQuery('#testID2').find('.test2').replaceWith('.test3');
```

Semantically, you are selecting the element with the ID `testID2`, then you are looking for any descendent elements with the class `test2` (does not exist) and then you are replacing that element with another element (elements anywhere in the page with the class `test3`) that also do not exist.

You need to do this:

```
jQuery('#testID2').addClass('test3').removeClass('test2');
```

This selects the element with the ID `testID2`, then adds the class `test3` to it. Last, it removes the class `test2` from that element.

Comment: +nudge over 1000. Nice explanation.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('#testID2').addClass('test3').removeClass('test2');
```

[jQuery addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) API reference

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$('#testID').addClass('nameOfClass');
```

or

```
$('#testID').removeClass('nameOfClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

.....

```
$("#testID #testID2").removeClass("test2").addClass("test3");
```

Because you have assigned an id to img too, you can simply do this too:

```
$("#testID2").removeClass("test2").addClass("test3");
```

And finally, you can do this too:

```
$("#testID img").removeClass("test2").addClass("test3");
```

Answer (score 0):

corrected Code:

```
jQuery('#testID2').addClass('test3').removeClass('test2');
```