# jQuery change 1 class of an element with multiple classes to a different class (a,b,c to a,b,d)

Tags: jquery, css, class

I'm using the following code to change the class of one element to a new class:

```
$("#change_color_scheme_1").on("click", function(){
    $(".bg1_color_1").attr("class","bg1_color_2");
});
```

This works great, however if my element has multiple classes attached to it such as `div class="class1 class2 class3"` it stops working. I assume it changes all of those 3 classes to one single class. Is there anyway to target and replace only one of those classes with jquery? So basically i can go from "`class1 class2 class3"` to `"class1 class2 class4"` without having to reattach classes `1` and `2`? So the code basically finds `class3` and replaces it with `class4`.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Find #ID, RemoveClass and AddClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407179/jquery-find-id-removeclass-and-addclass)

Comment: Look at jQuery's `addClass`, `removeClass` and `toggleClass` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*i can go from "class1 class2 class3" to "class1 class2 class4"*

You should use [**.removeClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

> Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.

and [**.addClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

> Adds the specified class(es) to each of the set of matched elements.

Use

```
$(".bg1_color_1").removeClass("class3").addClass("class4");
```